# Cryptsetup not finding libgcrypt.so after upgrade

Tags: cryptsetup

I am running a Fedora Core 13 with dm-crypt + luks, all standard with fedora distos.

After upgrading libgcrypt.so, cryptsetup moans at boot up that it can not find the library where it expects it to be  ( `/lib` ).

So I booted with a live cd, decrypted the root partition of that drive, and mounted my old hard drive, then I chroot'ed in there.

I ran cryptsetup and as expected it bombed out with the same error as when booting up...
I fixed the symlinks, and tested cryptsetup. It worked.

When I rebooted the same error was there again... I thought that somehow my changes was not being saved. So I booted back into the live OS, mounted the hdd & chroot'ed again, and to my amazement I found my symlink where I left it and cryptsetup working.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Why is cryptsetup still looking for the file in /lib and not finding it when its obviously there?!

P.S. I have also tried making duplicates of the libgcrypt library files in /lib as well as tried recompling cryptsetup from source, it all works 100% untill I reboot and then that error again!

I am thinkin' of just rebuilding that box, but I thought I'd ask you guys first?
Anyone come across a similar issue?

Comment: Your symlink might have been removed by `ldconfig`. Your description is confusing, could you edit it with the exact file names involved at each step?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding your `initramfs` files.  It's possible that a static copy of `libgcrypt` has been incorporated into the initial ram disk (to decrypt early disks, for example), and it is still the version prior to the package upgrade.

Comment: all good just reverted back to my old kernel, need to rebuild that beast soon!